# Moving elements to top/bottom in sortable_element

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I'm using `sortable_element` to sort some list with dragging and dropping, but I would like to have also some top/bottom buttons to move elements. Is there any javascript function that would act as if I dragged some element to the top/bottom of the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you easily simulate it with InsertBefore/InsertAfter or other DOM functions.